# sublime text 2 - display jsdocs while typing

Tags: sublime-text-2

I installed the JsDocs package and use it to document my code. ATM I'm using SublimeCodeIntel with `Alt+Click` to jump to the documentation, but this is quite annoying, especially when you just want to look up one little detail and then have to scroll back.

Assuming I've got a function `foo` like this:

```
/**
 * foo does some multiplication magic
 * @param  {Number} bar var number 1
 * @param  {Number} baz var number 2
 * @return {Number}     this equals bar*baz
 */
function foo(bar, baz) {
    return bar*baz;
}
```

Is there any package/plugin that displays the documentation of the function `foo` and its params and its return value when I type `foo(` (without scrolling to the documentation)?

Comment: That would be something... but nothing out there yet ey?!

Comment: This would be immensely useful...

Comment: @Laoujin I'm not too familiar with this idea; is it similar to intellisense - intelligent code completion where it shows what attributes you *could* use. Or is it something else?

Comment: Something that when you call a function you can see the JsDoc without going to the function implementation. Ideally this would be some sort of tooltip.
So yes, intellisense..

Comment: This would be fantastic. I am guessing this feature still does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think sublimeCodeIntel already does this by default.

please refer to [Using](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#using) section of the README, the feature you described is `manual code intelligence`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. "Manual Code Intelligence" is apparently limited to displaying `name(function)`: It only recognizes it as a function but comments (or even parameters) are not shown.